# How to interrupt Make spawned script?

Tags: bash, makefile, copy-paste, interrupt

How to make Ctrl-C interrupt Make spawned script.

My make object spawns a script. While its running, I hit Ctrl-C to interrupt it but there is no effect on it. I have to do Ctrl-Z to suspend the process and then kill %. Is there a way to interrupt the script with Ctrl-C?

I have the following in my Makefile:

```
run:
bash -c "trap 'trap - SIGINT SIGTERM ERR; exit 1' SIGINT SIGTERM ERR; $(MAKE) run_int"

run_int:
$(MAKE) simulate

simulate:
-$(CALL_TOOL)

CALL_TOOL = external_tool <options>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `make` issue, but rather one of the `external_program` you are launching via `make`. Presumably it catches and ignores `SIGINT`.

You can satisfy yourself of this by replacing `external_tool <options>` in the makefile presented with, say, `sleep 30`.  If you then run `make` from the terminal, you will find that Ctrl-C (in that terminal) interrupts the execution of `sleep` just fine:

> ```
> $ make
> bash -c "trap 'trap - SIGINT SIGTERM ERR; exit 1' SIGINT SIGTERM ERR; make run_int"
> make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jb/tmp'
> make simulate
> make[2]: Entering directory `/home/jb/tmp'
> sleep 10
> ^Cmake[2]: *** [simulate] Interrupt
> make[1]: *** [run_int] Interrupt
> make: *** [run] Error 1
> ```

Note also that your `run` rule is pointless.  Trapping SIGINT would be relevant only if that signal were being delivered to the shell in which you define the trap, and it isn't.  It's being delivered to the foreground process, which will be the one launched by the `simulate` rule unless you are superhumanly fast with your Ctrl-C keystroke.  You can remove that rule altogether, and still interrupt the process run by the `simulate` rule.  As already discussed, how that process responds to the signal is a separate question.